# context.commit is successful but is not reflected in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**ApplicationContext**

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext() : base("name=DbConnection") { }

    public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Credential> Credentials { get; set; } 
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-98TG6JE\SERVER_2014;Initial Catalog=SMBITS;User ID=sa;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**CreateAccountManager**

```
private readonly SqlConnection _dbConnection;
private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

public CreateAccountManager()
{
    _dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString);
    _context = new ApplicationContext();
}


public string CreateAccount(CreateAccountViewModel account)
{
    var result = "Failed in creating account";
    if (UserNameExists(account.UserName))
        return "Username is already taken";

    using (var context = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var acct = new Account
            {
                FirstName = account.FirstName,
                LastName = account.LastName,
                MiddleName = account.MiddleName,
                Status = "Active"
            };
            _context.Accounts.Add(acct);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            var credential = new Credential
            {
                AccountId = acct.AccountId,
                Password = account.Password,
                UserName = account.UserName
            };
            _context.Credentials.Add(credential);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            context.Commit();
            result = "Successfully created the account";
        }
        catch
        {
            context.Rollback();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public bool UserNameExists(string username)
{
    var result = false;
    const string query = "SELECT CredentialId from credential where UserName = @UserName";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _dbConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);

            _dbConnection.Open();

            var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
                result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return true;
            // ignore
        }
        finally
        {
            _dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I do not get any errors when I run the codes. The accountId increments, first it's 1 then 2 then 3 then 4, that means it is saving (as far as I know). But when I check my database that is stated in the web config, I do not see the inserted data. Also, I have a feeling that the data is being saved but probably into another database because, even if I use the same username again and again, I always get false, meaning, it cannot find a duplicate. So I am guessing that it really is being saved in another database. Can you show me where this database is and how do I point it to the right database.

Comment: Normally the Context class, in your case **ApplicationContext** contains the ConnectionString name in the constructor. Have you checked it ? Can you post the constructor of you ApplicationContext class here ?

Comment: There is one more point that looks confuse, you`re using **_context.SaveChanges();** and **context.Commit();** You see that they are different variables.

Comment: It is at the webconfig stated above. The context  and the _context are different variables yes.